# I want this function to create notepad file with each new record on new line "\n" i have tried many times but vain

Tags: python, tkinter, printf

```py
def print_(self, trv):
    rec = " "
    for line in trv.get_children():
        rec += " "
        for value in trv.item(line)['values']:
            rec += str(value) + " "

    textfile = open('Reportnew.txt', 'w')
    textfile.write(rec)
    textfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can barely understand your question because it's not formatted properly.

But if you want to append new lines use this

```
with open('Reportnew.txt', 'a') as textfile: #notice the 'a' instead of 'w'
    textfile.write(rec) #can write "\n" + rec OR rec + "\n" if rec doesn't have \n in it already
```

Or this

```
with open('Reportnew.txt', 'a') as textfile: #notice the 'a' instead of 'w'
    textfile.write("\n")
    textfile.write(rec)
```

Comment: I think OP wants `"\n"`s in between each record.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```py
def print_(self, trv):
    rec = ""
    for line in trv.get_children():
        rec += " ".join(map(str, trv.item(line)['values'])) + "\n"

    with open("Reportnew.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(rec)
```

I used `" ".join(...)` to join all of the items adding spaces in between. I also added `"\n"` at the end of each record.